# android.support.v7.widget item.SearchView long click event

Tags: java, android, xml, events

I'm trying to perform long click on searchView menu item in xml menu in android java.

I want to find a way in java code to perform long click on this menu item(the icon not the searchbar) the menu item use app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

I tried many solutions but none of those working.

Can you lend me an hand please?

EDIT:

Here the code that i try

```
    searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    final int itemId = searchItem.getItemId();
    View actionView = searchItem.getActionView();

    /** define view on long click listener */
    final View.OnLongClickListener toolbarItemLongClicked = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        int counter;
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            Log.d("longclick", "Long click performed");
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have tried.

Comment: I edited the main post